# can't commit file delete in SVN repo; Internal Error: Non-modifying file change

Tags: svn, hook, commit, pre-commit

i seem to be no longer able to commit file deletions in my repository.

```
Error Commit failed (details follow):
Error Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 1) with output:
Error Internal error: Non-modifying file change.
```

it looks strange to me that this is nowhere to be found on the net.

any idea?

i am using tortoise 1.7.7 and SVN 1.7.6

my pre-commit.bat

```
PATH C:\msys\bin
PATH %PATH%;C:\Program Files\csvn\Python25
PATH %PATH%;C:\Program Files\csvn\bin
set PYTHON=C:\Program Files\csvn\Python25
set PYTHONPATH=C:\Program Files\csvn\lib\svn-python
bash %1/hooks/pre-commit %1 %2
```

and my pre-commit hook

```
REPOS="$1"
TXN="$2"

: ${PATH:=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin}
export PATH


svnlook log -t "$TXN" "$REPOS" | \
   grep "[a-zA-Z0-9]" > /dev/null || \
   { echo >&2 "An empty commit message is not allowed."; exit 1; }


python $REPOS/hooks/svnperms.py -r "$REPOS" -t "$TXN" || exit 1

# Validate the changes made by this transaction.
python $REPOS/hooks/pre-commit-check.py "$REPOS" "$TXN" || exit 1

# All checks passed, so allow the commit.
exit 0
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Please post your $REPO_PATH/hooks/pre-commit file contents (or pre-commit.bat if you're using MS Win OS).

Comment: getting a feeling this is coming from our python script after upgrading to svn 1.7.6

Comment: I'm not a python master, but it might help if you also put here REPOS/hooks/svnperms.py and $REPOS/hooks/pre-commit-check.py scripts. Seems to me, they might be buggy, ie. svn-version dependent.

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but I think `svnlook diff` output format could have changed in new version. Might be the point if your python used that.